# Android Twitter Fabric SDK conflict with Google GSON

Tags: android, twitter, gradle, gson, twitter-fabric

I'm having difficulties  integrating Twitter Fabric SDK to my app. I followed the steps of the [Twitter tutorial](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate) and everyhting went fine but when I try to build my project with gradle, I get this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
D:\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --output ...
Error Code: 2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/gson/JsonSerializer;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

I tried removing my static Gson library from my app module lib folder and everything went fine afterwards. Same when removing the line adding twitter sdk from the gradle module dependencies so I'm pretty sure there is some kind of conflict between these two and I'm looking to resolve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

In case it could be of any use to people out there here is my gradle app module file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven{ url 'https://maven.fabric.io/repo'}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The fabric SDK must be using Gson internally, therefore if it is exposed you can just use this as well and remove Gson from your `/libs/` . Alternatively import both librarys as dependencies in Gradle and then you can exclude `Gson` from `Fabric`

Comment: @Blundell Thanks for your answer. That's what I thought ! I'll look into removing Gson from Fabric SDK since I browsed every package inside the SDK and didn't find anything like it. Do you have any insights about removing Gson from the SDK in gradle ?

Comment: Yeah it would be like this, but with your relevant libraries: `compile('com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.1') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }`

Comment: @Blundell `compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
        exclude module: 'gson'
    }`
did the trick. Do you want to post the answer (extra reputation etc) or do you want me to do it ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm a Twitter Android developer.

Try running `./gradlew app:dependencies` to see all the dependencies of your gradle tasks. Your compile dependencies will include something like:

```
+--- com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:1.0.0
|    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.6.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    |    +--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.0.0
```

which shows that GSON is indeed used by Fabric internally.

My recommendation would be to remove GSON from your libs/ folder and add it as a direct dependency in your build.gradle instead of excluding it from the Twitter deps graph. You may as well take advantage of the dependency resolution mechanisms in the build tool.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])  // Maybe remove this.
    compile project(':facebook')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'  // Added.
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. It seems to be the way android studio/gradle want things to be so I'll certainly try that :) Nice of you to complete my understanding of gradle and the way it manages dependencies

Comment: it works for me after delete all 'Build' files :), thanks

Answer (score 13):

The fabric SDK must be using Gson internally, therefore if it is exposed you can just use this as well and remove Gson from your /libs/ .

Alternatively import both librarys as dependencies in Gradle and then you can exclude Gson from Fabric.

Exclude gson from Fabric like this:

```
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.0.0@aar') { 
       transitive = true; 
       exclude module: 'gson' 
}
```

Comment: The same method can be used on other packages of Twitter. For instance:  `compile ('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter-core:3.1.1') { exclude module: 'gson' }`